# hmatrix install error issue with sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hmatrix

I installed hmatrix in a sandbox, which gets through the install process but then then linker hangs up with... 

`Linking dist/dist-sandbox-34d68aef/build/wavelets/wavelets ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSwavelets-0.1.0_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSlens-4.0.7_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSzlib-0.5.4.1_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSvoid-0.6.1_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSutf8-string-0.3.7_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSsplit-0.2.2_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSreflection-1.4_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSprofunctors-4.0.2_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSparallel-3.2.0.4_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSexceptions-0.3.3_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSbifunctors-4.1.1_p
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSsemigroupoids-4.0_p`

cabal looks like:

`Name:                   wavelets
Version:                0.1.0
Author:                 Scott Murphy
Maintainer:             Scott Murphy
License:                BSD3
License-File:           LICENSE`

Cabal-Version:          >= 1.10
Build-Type:             Simple

Library
  Default-Language:     Haskell2010
  HS-Source-Dirs:       src
  GHC-Options:          -Wall
  Exposed-Modules:      Data.Wavelets
  Other-Modules:        Data.Wavelets.Internal
  Build-Depends:        base                     >= 4         &&   < 5
                       ,bytestring               >= 0.9       &&   < 1.0
                       ,mtl                      >= 2.1       &&   < 2.2
                       ,lens                     >= 3.9
                       ,text                     >= 0.11.3.1 
                       ,transformers             >= 0.3.0.0
                       ,vector                   >= 0.10.9.1
                       ,unordered-containers     >= 0.2.3.3
                       ,hstatistics

Test-Suite spec
  Type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Default-Language:     Haskell2010
  Hs-Source-Dirs:       src
                      , test
  Ghc-Options:          -Wall
  Main-Is:              Spec.hs
  Build-Depends:        base
                      , hspec 
                      , wavelets
                      , vector

Executable wavelets
    main-is:            Main.hs
    HS-Source-Dirs:     src
    build-depends:      base
                      , wavelets
                      , vector

```
ghc-options:      -threaded -O2 -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto
```

Source-Repository head
  Type:                 git
--  Location:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed prof -fprof-auto  and it worked!